# Leaflet - change the color of polyline while opening a popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, geojson

Here's what I've got. When I hover the mouse cursor over the polyline, it changes color.

```
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    var popupContent = "<div class=popup>Sample text in popup.</div>";
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    layer.on('mouseover', function(){
    layer.setStyle({ color: "#0000FF" });
    });
    layer.on('mouseout', function(){
    layer.setStyle({ color: "#000" });
    });
        }
```

How to keep the polyline's color change while popup is open?

Example:

- polyline is black as default
- it changes to blue, while I'm hovering the cursor over it
- when I click on the polyline, popup is opening and polyline stays blue
- when I close the popup, polyline's color backs to black (default)

Answer (score 1):

Polyline also have events such as `popupopen, popupclose`. You can change color when popup is open (also you must disable events connected with hover using method `.off()`).

More info here [Popup events](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#polyline-popupopen)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very skillful. Is there any working example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to keep track if a popup is open:

```
var popupIsVisible = false;

polyline.on('mouseover', function (e) {
    if (!popupIsVisible) e.target.setStyle({color: "#0000FF"});
});

polyline.on('mouseout', function (e) {
    if (!popupIsVisible) e.target.setStyle({color: "#000"});
});

polyline.on('popupopen', function (e) {
    popupIsVisible = true;
    e.target.setStyle({color: "#0000FF"});
});

polyline.on('popupclose', function (e) {
    popupIsVisible = false;
    e.target.setStyle({color: "#000"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep opacity to zero (o) and change color to any color you want. For e.g.

```
L.geoJSON(statesData, {
    style: innerstyle
}).addTo(map);

function innerstyle(feature) {
    return {
        color: "#CF01FD",
        weight: 1,
        fillOpacity: .01
    }
}
```

//here "statesData" is any geojson dataset

[This](https://imgur.com/gallery/pidYdyd) is what it looks like